# JTabbedPane, addChangeListener() only queries database on the last tab

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

Ok, so I am stuck with these loops. I have a `tabbedPane` and I add tabs to it, via data from database which I get with the line `con.getKat()` - (list of strings that represent categories). Then every tab should contain a `JTable` with contents from my database with all the records that contain the category(String) from the selected tab. The problem is that every tab triggers the `ChangeListener()` (which i check with `System.out.println(kategorija))` but only the last tab displays data (no matter how i add or remove tabs it's always the last tab). Might be something silly here but any help appreciated.

```
ArrayList<String> ls = con.getKat();
    for(String s : ls){
        pane = new JScrollPane();
        tabbedPane.addTab(s, null, pane, null);
    }
tabbedPane.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            kategorija = tabbedPane.getTitleAt(tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex());  
            System.out.println(kategorija);
            ArrayList<Ceni> artikli = con.getHuroCeni(kategorija);
            dtm.setRowCount(0);
            for(Ceni c : artikli){
                dtm.addRow(new Object[]{c.sifra, c.name, String.valueOf(c.cena1), c.tarifa});
                table = new JTable();
                table.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 16));
                table.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED, new Color(128, 128, 128), null, null, null));
                pane.setViewportView(table);
                table.setModel(dtm);                    
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: `pane.setViewportView(table);` - here `pane` always refers to the last tab's panel!

Comment: @Prashant why is that and where should i 'setViewportView()' then?